# Where in the element is the event handler function that was attached to it by jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have an jquery element and I attach a function to it

```
element.on('click', function(){
    // do stuff
});
```

If I want to find the function that does the `//do stuff`, where inside the element would I find it, in order to execute it manually if needed. (`element[???]();` `->` `//does stuff`)

Comment: When do you want to "find" it? Who shall find it?

Answer (score 1):

if you want to reuse that function just make it a standalone function and bind it to the click event

```
function doStuff(e) {
    // ...
}

element.bind('click', doStuff);
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you mean manually triggering an event handler. Use:

```
element.trigger('click');
```